Are these two statements the same statement under the given constraints?
This question is a follow-up of this other question, which I posted a few months ago and which received a valid answer. I will now re-state the original question, and will add the new information at the end.
Let $A$ and $B$ be arbitrary finite sets, and let $f:A\to B$ be a function with domain $A$ and codomain $B$.
I am reading a paper whose main result reads like this:

Let the function $f:A\to B$ satisfy Properties 1 and 2. Then, the function $f:A\to B$ satisfies Property 3 if and only if it satisfies Property 4.

I am wondering whether the above statement is equivalent to the following one:

The function $f:A\to B$ satisfies Properties 1, 2 and 3 if and only if it satisfies Property 4.

Let me state the problem symbolically. Let $P_1$, $P_2$, $P_3$ and $P_4$ be arbitrary sets, where $f\in P_i$ if and only if $f$ satisfies Property $i$, where $i\in\{1,2,3,4\}$. I will now symbolically re-write statements 1 and 2:

$(f\in P_1\cap P_2)\Rightarrow[(f\in P_3)\Leftrightarrow(f\in P_4)]$.

$(f\in P_1\cap P_2\cap P_3)\Leftrightarrow(f\in P_4)$.


NEW INFORMATION
In the answer to my original question, I was told that statements 1 and 2 are not identical unless Property 4 implies Properties 1 and 2. I have now checked the paper that prompted this question, and it turns out that Property 4 very clearly implies Properties 1 and 2.
In my field, it is common to state theorems in the form of statement 2: namely,
The function $f:A\to B$ satisfies Properties 1, 2 and 3 if and only if it satisfies Property 4.
I am therefore trying to figure out the reasons why the author of said paper chose to state his theorem in the unconventional way he did, hoping that understanding this will help me see whether I need to state my theorem in this unconventional way too. After carefully examining the paper, I believe that the reason he might have chosen to state his theorem the way he did is because Property 3 is defined only on functions that satisfy Property 1, but I am not sure at all.
So, assume these two new constraints:

Property 4 implies Properties 1 and 2,
Property 3 is defined only on functions that already satisfy Property 1.

QUESTION: Under these two new constraints, are statements 1 and 2 equivalent?
EDIT: Following Naïm Favier’s comment, here’s the paper we’re talking about:
Koray, S. (2000). Self-Selective Social Choice Functions Verify Arrow and Gibbard-Satterthwaite Theorems. Econometrica, 68.4, pp. 981 - 996.
In particular, I’m thinking of Theorem 2, p. 990.

Obviously constraint 2 doesn't make a difference, so yes statements 1 and 2 are equivalent as you were told in the other answer. Hard to say why the author chose a particular statement without knowing which paper we're talking about.

Thank you for your comment. I am not sure it helps, but I have edited my original question to link to the paper I am talking about. EDIT: Could you elaborate on the claim that constraint 2 does not make a difference?

Well... kind of, but not really. For an analogy, suppose I made the following statement:
"If $\frac{0}{x} = 0$, then $x \neq 0$."
In some sense one could claim this is true: if "$\frac{0}{x} = 0$" is a true statement, then $x$ can't be zero. But the problem is that if $x=0$, then the antecedent isn't exactly false, so much as it's poorly formed. This is because the notion of equality assumes you have some sort of mathematical object on each side that you're making a statement about (that they are the same object).
Since $\frac{0}{0}$ is undefined, making a claim about it isn't false - it's just not really saying anything. And that means you can't use standard logical tools on the above claim - for example, its contrapositive is "If $x = 0$, then $\frac{0}{x} \neq 0$", but this is not a true statement because again, the inequality doesn't mean anything.
The way mathematicians would typically phrase this claim is as follows:
"Let $x \neq 0$. Then $\frac{0}{x} = 0$."
Now the equality makes sense, because both sides of the equation are well-defined.
Now, going back to your question, if we were to change your second (new) constraint to "Property 3 implies Property 1", then your alternate phrasing would be correct. But that's not what the constraint is.
So I believe you're more or less correct about why the author phrased it the way they did: Because Property 3 only being defined on functions with Property 1 is not the same as Property 3 implying Property 1. As with the toy example above, using the "Let" phrasing makes the statement more correct.


QUESTION: Under the bulleted constraints, are statements 1 and 2 equivalent?

Property 4 implies Properties 1 and 2,
Property 3 is defined only on functions that already satisfy Property 1.


$(f\in P_1\cap P_2)\Rightarrow[(f\in P_3)\Leftrightarrow(f\in P_4)].$

$(f\in P_1\cap P_2\cap P_3)\Leftrightarrow(f\in P_4).$



Under the assumption of just the first bullet, statement 1 is indeed equivalent to statement 2.
This is because of the tautology
$$\bigg(D → (A∧B)\bigg) → \bigg(\Big((A∧B) → (C↔D)\Big) ↔ \Big((A ∧ B∧C) ↔ D\Big)\bigg).$$
P.S. The second bullet implies $(f\in P_3\implies f\in P_1),$ but not vice versa: the latter doesn't imply the second bullet.
